# function to multiply (and saturate) 2 int32_t arguments

Tags: multiplication

I need to write a function, which multiplies and saturates 2 arguments (int32_t) and returns also int32_t. Everything inside must be counted within limits of int32_t. If multiplying under/overflows int32_t the result muse be saturated by INT32MAX and INT32MIN.

my solution is following: but it has

```
int32_t multiple_or_saturate(int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
  if(((a >= 0) && (b >= 0)) || ((a < 0) && (b < 0)))
  {
    if((INT32_MAX / a) >= b)
    {
      return(a * b);
    }
    else
    {
      return(INT32_MAX);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if((INT32_MIN / a ) <= b)
    {
      return(a * b);
    }
    else
    {
      return(INT32_MIN);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the division is quite expensive here. It would be more efficient to store the result of the multiplication in a 64 bit variable, then check the result and then saturate it if needed.

Some compilers also support the usage of MMX intrinsics for saturating arithmetic. There are most probably an assembler instruction for it (depending on hardware of course), you just need to use a compiler that knows haw to use it.

Comment: unfortunatelly our processor does not support 64bits data type.